# New Magento VM redirecting to old website

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I created a new Azure VM machine using the clone/image of a previous one.

However, when I can `newwebsite.com/magento`, it's automatically redirecting to `oldwebsite.com/magento`. I looked at the .htaccess in the main magento directory, and I found no reference to the old website. Also, I cleared the cache and sessions, but neither of those things seemed to fix the issue.

What could be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Access your Magento DB & find core_config_data table
- Run the following command:

> select * from core_config_data where path like '%base%url%';

- This will display the current base_urls set in Magento.
- To change the base URLs, execute the following commands:

> update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path =
>   'web/unsecure/base_url';
>
> update core_config_data set value = 'http://domainname/' where path =
>   'web/secure/base_url';